# oncreate is getting called when application comes to foreground

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have SplashScreen Activity and MainActivity. Once SplashScreen timeouts I am calling

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

It is taking me to the onCreate of Mainactivity. Now I press device home button and keeps the app in backgroung for long time and when I am bringing the app to the foreground by clicking on Launcher icon it is taking me to the onCreate of MainActivity. Here I am doubting if device is killing my app from Application backstack then it should start from SplashScreen Activity instead of MainActivity. I have not set any launch mode tag in Manifest.xml. could you please help me

Comment: I never get my splash screen to work properly, so I finally used a "splash fragment"! hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I press device home button and keeps the app in backgroung for long time and when I am bringing the app to the foreground by clicking on Launcher icon it is taking me to the onCreate of MainActivity.

Yes, that is the expected behavior. If the app has been in the background long enough that the OS has killed your app's process, your MainActivity will need to go through its full creation procedure, including `onCreate()` (though you should see that the `savedInstanceState` Bundle is non-null during this re-creation).

> Here I am doubting if device is killing my app from Application backstack then it should start from SplashScreen Activity instead of MainActivity.

I think you misunderstand what the OS killing your app's process means. It doesn't mean that your app has been "quit", and it doesn't mean that your app will start over from scratch just like when it is launched for the first time. In fact, it is explicitly **not** supposed to appear as though it's starting for the first time. The main idea is that the OS killing your app's process shouldn't be something the user ever realizes happened; they should start right where they left off.

Comment: you mean even though I made SplashScreen as MAIN & LAUNCHER, system will always starts where it was left considering it was killed by OS

Comment: @RahulMatte yes. Those manifest details only matter when you're doing a cold start of the app (like after you reboot your phone or force quit your app from the "recents" menu).

Answer (score 0):

Set the intent filter in your `manifest.xml` in your `SplashActivity` as Below

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now if your app will first search for the Splash Screen at App Start Up .Also remember that , When you are calling - `finish() ;` on a activity that activity is removed from the Stack.So When you come back to the App Again you will  able to see your `HomeActivity`.

Comment: "So When you come back to the App Again you will able to see your HomeActivity" yes I agree but it should be in onResume of HomeActivity not in onCreate